# Is there a way to call my javascript parameters in this html tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to make a JQuery plugin that takes an initial parameter and executes it in a HTML tag. Is this even possible to do. If it can be done, how?

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.toggle_box = function (object) { 
    this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        var $box = $('<div id=*'object' parameter here*></div>');

        //more code

    });
};
})(jQuery);

$('div.clickable_box').toggle_box(object);
```

Comment: Please explain your question better. What is `*'object' parameter here*` supposed to mean?

Comment: String concatenation? I don't get the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

With jQuery you can associate arbitrary data with a give element

So, for example

```
var div = $("div")[0];
jQuery.data(div, "test", { first: 16, last: "pizza!" });
```

Here you find the first DIV element and store an object on the key "test".

You can also call data directly on an element like this:

```
$("div")[0].data("test", { first: 16, last: "pizza!" });
```

You can also add data to the tags like this:

```
<div data-role="page" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'></div>
```

Then all of these would be true

```
$("div").data("role") === "page";
$("div").data("lastValue") === 43;
$("div").data("hidden") === true;
$("div").data("options").name === "John";
```

Finally, these two have the same result:

```
$("div")[0].data("test", { first: 16, last: "pizza!" });
```

and

```
<div data-test='{"first": 16, "last": "pizza!" }'></div>
```

Here is the documentation :

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @ericwalier - Glad to help, welcome to SO.  Please up-vote the question if it helped and select it as the correct answer (if it is).